# React Application only displays public/index.html when using NGINX

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose, react-router

I am attempting to deploy a React app with Docker to an Nginx image.

Currently, once the build is complete and Docker is run, I can access the page through `localhost:xxxx`, but only the contents of the `public/index.html` in my React application shows (i.e. favicon, site title) but no other content displays.

As a note, running `npm start` displays the page without any issues.

Below are my `Dockerfile`, `nginx.conf`, and general structure of the React application for reference:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14.7-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
   listen: 80
   server_name test-frontend;

   location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri /index.html;
   }

   error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

   location = /50x.html {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   }
}
```

***React App Structure***

```
test-frontend/
├── Dockerfile
├── .dockerignore
├── jsconfig.json
├── nginx.conf
├── npm-debug.log
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── nodemodules/
  ├── package/
  │   ├── ...
  │   ├── ...
  │   ├── ...
  └── .../
├── public/
  ├── favicon.ico
  ├── icon.png
  ├── index.html <--- this loads fine.
  ├── manifest.json
├── src/
  ├── assets/
  ├── components/
  ├── views/
  ├── index.js <--- this does not populate.
  ├── routes.js <--- routes are ignored.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you run `docker run <image name> ls /usr/share/nginx/html`? I'm curious what is actually getting copied into that directory.

Comment: @NickODell I have only the following when I run the command you've stated:

```50x.html, icon.png, asset-manifest.json, favicon.ico, index.html, manifest.json, precache-manifest.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.js, service-worker.js, static```